# Why does @property require a newline before definition

Tags: python, python-internals

Why does the python parser not allow the following?

```
@property def link(self): return 'https://github.com/%s' % self.repo
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It does allow it with a newline of course:

```
@property 
def link(self): 
    return 'https://github.com/%s' % self.repo
```

Is this considered a bug, or why does the parser not allow that?

As a reference a lot of other statements allow something like "either newline or ". For example, the [python delete statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html) has the grammar:

```
del_stmt:
    | 'del' del_targets &(';' | NEWLINE)
```

Whereas the decorator is only:

```
decorators: ('@' named_expression NEWLINE )+
```

So I'm just curious why the property doesn't allow 'jamming them together'. Sometimes I find it helpful when I have a long class where a lot of the fields are properties.

Comment: @python_user I'm used to doing a lot of things on one line: `def square(n): return n*n`, `class MyException: pass`, ...etc

Comment: Line breaks are extremely important in Python syntax. You wouldn't expect to be able to do `print(x) print(y)`, or arbitrarily delete line breaks between most other lines of Python code, would you?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica for that I could do: `>>> print('hi');print('hello')`. But for a property I cannot do: `@property; def hello(self): print("hi")`

Comment: I am not sure if this helps, I am seeing `decorators: ('@' named_expression NEWLINE )+` in python [grammar documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)